# Non-text email attachments showing up without content in rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, attachment, actionmailer, mailer

I am trying to send an html email with attachments using a mailer in my rails application. I am able to send text attachments, but when I try anything else the attachments are coming through the email but showing up with nothing in them. I have tried a variety of files including pdf's and png's. I am not getting any errors in the program or in the log. 
Here is my code:

From my mailer:

```
 attachments['test']=File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images','Hello.txt'))

 attachments['mcp_logo.png']=File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images','mcp_logo.png'))

    mail(to: recipient, from: 'Email@email.com', subject: 'Test Moodifer Email') do |format|
        format.html {render 'moodemail'}
        format.text {render :text => @text}
    end
```

From my controller:

```
MoodMailer.moodemail(@text,@recipient,@name,@mood,@time,@type).deliver
```

And here is what the log shows when trying to send the png as an attachment:

```
----=_mimepart_534ca2511ae1c_11c818d488c18274
Content-Type: image/png;
 charset=UTF-8;
 filename=mcp_logo.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=mcp_logo.png
Content-ID: <534ca251eac9_11c818d488c180ca@owner-PC.mail>

iVBORwo=
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to put all the images in `public directory`. Please make you have provided the right path.

Comment: Thanks for answering. They were not in my public directory. I went ahead and added them there and changed the path. I'm still not having any luck. I can verify that they are where the application is looking because I get an error if I misspell the path or file name.

Comment: @user3512720 you are r8. but can you just try to put one static image in public directory and check if it is coming or not. and in the development.rb please make config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true